# How to cycle focus through textboxes only

Tags: firefox, iceweasel

I would like to control my browser completely from the keyboard.

I use Iceweasel (≈ Firefox) on a Debian system.

Is there a way put the cursor in a text box?

Or perhaps in any text box, and then cycle them, text box only?

Right now, I use the links-only search to get to a close-by link, and then Tab (or Alt-Tab), but often not even that works as there seems to be some contra-intuitive tab order defined.

Comment: There is a way to change the way that focus works to a more intuitive way where instead of using the tab-order, you can use the arrow keys to change focus to elements directionally. I think that Opera and/or Safari support it by default while Firefox needs a setting to be changed. I cannot seem to find it at the moment though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle focus through text fields only, go to `about:config` and set the `accessibility.tabfocus` preference to `1`.

---

See Also:

- [MozillaZine: **accessibility.tabfocus**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.tabfocus)